# Python Extension with openmp in OS X

Tags: python, c, macos, gcc, openmp

I have created a python extension that works correctly in Linux but doesn't work in os x.

The C code makes use of the openmp library.

The C compiler that is preinstalled in os x is clang and the preinstalled python has been built with clang. That clang doesn't support openmp.

I can compile and run my code by installing gcc-6 by:

```
    brew install gcc
```

I can build my libary by including in the file setup.py the environment variable CC:

```
    os.environ["CC"]="/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/bin/gcc-6"
```

And I include the gcc library path in the setup configuration:

```
    library_dirs = ["/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/","../build/"],
```

But then I obtain errors when I load my library from python:

```
    import myLibraryName
```

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/LIBIRWLS.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/6/libgomp.1.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/6/libgomp.1.dylib

What should I do? What is the correct procedure create a python extension in OS X that makes use of the openmp library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thik I have solved this issue. This is the project I am working on:

https://github.com/RobeDM/LIBIRWLS

In resume:

1 - I installed gcc6 by

```
brew install gcc
```

2 - Then I declared the path to gcc in a environment variables in the file setup.py:

```
os.environ["CC"]=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/bin/gcc-6
```

3 - I left the CFLAGS environment variable empty:

```
os.environ["CFLGAS"]=""
```

4 - In the extension module I included the file libgomp.a associated to gcc6 and I used the extra ling arg "static":

```
ext_modules = [ 
    Extension('LIBIRWLS',
        include_dirs=['.','../include/',np.get_include()],
        sources = ['myexample.c'],
        extra_objects = ["/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/libgomp.a",
            ....Object files of my library
        ],
        library_dirs = ["../build/"],
        extra_compile_args=['-Wno-cpp','-static','-lgomp','-lblas','-llapack'],
        extra_link_args=['-static']
    )
    ]
```

setup(
        name = 'LIBNAME',
        version = '1.0',
        description="My extension description",
        install_requires=[
            'numpy',
            'scipy',
        ],
        url='https://myurl.com',
        ext_modules = ext_modules
      )